# Designing a mongodb schema featuring a many-to-many relation

Tags: mongodb

Hi I've begun learning Mongo on a small home project to determine if its viable as a solution for one of our products at work. Before heading down the path I've dreamed up I wanted to run this by stack overflow to determine if this structure is sane and that data can be efficiently accessed n years from now.

The application is one that collects spreads for football games and allows users to place mock bets. This opens the door for all sorts of interesting analytics down the line from betting patterns to how spreads change over time etc.

- users

  - bets[]
- teams

  - standings[]
- games

  - away team{}
  - home team{}
  - bets[]

You'll notice from the list above I have bets listed twice. This is one of the big questions I have. Where would a doc that stores the game a user bet on be stored? In the games or in the users collection. Both make sense really. If I store it one vs the other than I have to query a big list in the other for showing the data. For instance if I have users.bets then I when I want to show all the bets for a given game I have to look for that game.id in all of users.bets and vice-versa. Is this efficient? Sane?

I guess this is a struggling point for me. I know how to deal with many-to-many in a relational database, but not here. Is a 3rd collection for storing the many-to-many still the way to go in mongo.

Opinions and reference material are welcomed.

Comment: The MongoDb docs cover these topics very well. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/ The right choice will be determined mostly by the types of queries you want to write. You should figure out what those are specifically. MongoDb may not be a good match.

Comment: Typically with mongodb schema design your most important concern is read-efficiency, while keeping writes reasonably efficient and atomic.  Sometimes this will mean embedding, sometimes duplication.  There's also the issue of unbound collections; if an array may grow arbitrarily it is ill suited for embedding.  IMO, here I'd go with a separate bets doc referencing users+games.  Bets are probably data-independent enough to warrant their own collection, and this is scalable and easily queryable by user and/or game.

Comment: @WiredPrairie thanks. I know it might not be the best, the point of this is to learn mongo and have fun doin it.

Comment: @numbers1311407 thanks ill look into that design and think about the queries.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with denormalizing data - if it gets queried in multiple places, then in your application it makes sense to store it in multiple places.

Things to consider when you are thinking how to structure things is what the data will look like in X months when there is a lot more of it.

If this application collects data for many years, it might be problematic to have all the bet history embedded in the user document - will you need all of their history every time you load their document?  Or will most of it be useless and not relevant?

I would encourage you to consider storing data you need "together" together, but be realistic and critical about whether you will always need all of that data.